# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'mydb.alien' doesn't exist

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven

Alien.java(Pojo class),
this is my pojo class

```
  package com.me.Hive1;
  import javax.persistence.Entity;
  import javax.persistence.Id;

  @Entity
  public class Alien {          
        @Id
        private int id;
        private String name;
        public int getId()
        {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id)
        {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getName()
        {
             return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name)
        {
             this.name = name;
        }
     }
```

App.java(Main Class),
this is main class.

```
package com.me.Hive1;
            import org.hibernate.Session;
            import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
            import org.hibernate.Transaction;
            import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
            //MAIN CLASS
            /**
             * Hello world!
             *
             */
            public class App 
            {
                public static void main( String[] args )
                {
                    System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
                    Alien a = new Alien();
                    a.setId(101);
                    a.setName("bhanu");
                    try{
                    Configuration fact = new Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(Alien.class);
                    SessionFactory sf = fact.buildSessionFactory();
                    Session session = sf.openSession();
                    Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
                    session.save(a);
                    t.commit();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
```

configuration file(hibernate.cfg.xml),
this is my hibernate configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!--Configuration file-->
        <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
                "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
        <hibernate-configuration>
            <session-factory>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb</property>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
                <property name="hibernate.hbm2dll.auto">create</property>
                <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
                <mapping class="com.me.Hive1.Alien" resource="Alien.hbm.xml"/>
            </session-factory>
        </hibernate-configuration>
```

Alien.hbm.xml(mapping file) ,
this is mapping file,is it optional ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <!-- Generated Jul 5, 2017 1:44:20 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.5.0.Final -->
    <hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="com.me.Hive1.Alien" table="alien">
            <id name="id" type="int">
                <column name="ID" />
                <generator class="assigned" />
            </id>
            <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
                <column name="NAME" />
            </property>
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

i am getting exception(Console output) this is the exception i am getting,
don't know i am struck

```
    Hello World!
    Jul 05, 2017 4:13:18 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
    INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.10.Final}
    Jul 05, 2017 4:13:18 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
    INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
    Jul 05, 2017 4:13:19 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
    Jul 05, 2017 4:13:19 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
    WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
    Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
    Jul 05, 2017 4:13:19 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb]
    Jul 05, 2017 4:13:19 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
    Jul 05, 2017 4:13:19 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
    Jul 05, 2017 4:13:19 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
    INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
    Wed Jul 05 16:13:19 IST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
    Jul 05, 2017 4:13:19 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
    INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    Jul 05, 2017 4:13:24 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
    WARN: SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
    Jul 05, 2017 4:13:24 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
    ERROR: Table 'mydb.alien' doesn't exist
    Jul 05, 2017 4:13:24 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
    INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
    Jul 05, 2017 4:13:24 PM org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl mapManagedFlushFailure
    ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement]
    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1441)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:491)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3201)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2411)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:220)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
        at com.me.Hive1.App.main(App.java:25)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3003)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3503)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:589)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1435)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'mydb.alien' doesn't exist
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:536)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:513)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:115)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:1983)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1826)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2034)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1970)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5001)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1955)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:205)
        ... 18 more
```

Comment: Even if i didn't use **maven** i am getting the same exception, i have been trying from one week no solution till now please some one help me with this thing.what's the **reason** for this??????????

Comment: try this:  @Column private String name; instead of private String name; in entity class

Comment: Can you share your exact table name or create table SQL?

Comment: @Nidhi257,   `1)org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] 2)Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error calling Driver#connect  3)Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'mydb'. This exception raised for your changes!!!!

Comment: @DarshitChokshi, table??????? hibernate supposed to create table right??? i didn't created any table, but it is saying **mydb.alien** even i don't know!

Comment: Is there any problem with my mysql, hibernate jars and mysql-connector jar versions??mysqk->5.7.1,hibernate->5.2.10, mysql-connector-->5.1.42.

Comment: @DarshitChokshi,i have a doubt that do i need to create a table before using it in mapping file and pojo class??????what if i want to create new table through our program, hibernate supports it right(auto ddl feature) how can i do it???       by the way it's working thank you so much : ) please i need to know the answer for the above questions!!!!!

Comment: @Nidhi257, thank you !!!!!

Comment: @bhanu See its totally depends on you, If your table structure is not fixed yet than you can pass that overhead to hibernate to create or update tables. But according to me your database design must be ready before starting the development. Happy Coding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

In your configuration file change value of this property:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
```

Hope this will help you ;)

Comment: finally, i got some fuel to run hibernate, thank you so much

Comment: The same problem and this did not help.